# eventListener added to element before adding element to DOM. Does not apply

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an eventListener to a div that I create dynamically. However, it does not apply to the div when I inspect it in Chrome.
This is what I do:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  console.log('test');
});

var root = document.getElementById('root');
root.appendChild(inner);
```

Can I not add an eventListener to an element before it is added to the DOM?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/2025923) answer.

Comment: @Tushar The eventListener is there, but set to the whole document. It also does not execute the callback function.

Comment: As shown in the answer, you need to bind the event on `document` and check if the element is the targeted one using the `event` object which is passed as a parameter to the event handler.

Comment: I had to modify the hasClass function, but it works now and targets the correct element. Problem now is that only a column of 1 pixels on the div is actually clickable :/

Comment: Right the answer you gave worked @Tushar

Comment: I just need to figure out how to get the eventListener to apply to all the elements inside the div. Currently that is not the case.